# real analysis : futher properties of the integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $g$ be an increasing function on $J_1 = [a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and for each fixed t in $J_2=[c,d]$,

suppose that the integral

$$F(t) = \int_{a}^{b}f(x,t)dg(x) $$ exists.

If the partial derivative $\cfrac{\partial}{\partial t}f$ is continuous on $J_1\times J_2$,

then the derivative $F^\prime$ exists on $J_2$ and is given by

$$F'(t) = \int_{a}^{b}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(x,t)dg(x) $$

How can I prove this problem?

Comment: You are sure you did not mix up something?

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant $f_t=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ rather.
\begin{eqnarray*}F'(t)&=&\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\left(\int_a^b f(x,t+h)\,dg(x)-\int_a^b f(x,t)\,dg(x)\right)\\
&=&\lim_{h\to 0}\int_a^b\frac{f(x,t+h)-f(x,t)}{h}\,dg(x)\\
&=&\lim_{h\to 0}\int_a^b f_t(x,t+\zeta)\,dg(x)\\
&=&\int_a^b f_t(x,t)\,dg(x)
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\zeta=\zeta(h,x)$ satisfies $0\le \zeta\le h$ by Mean Value theorem. Continuity of $f_t$ implies that it is bounded on $[a,b]$, and the last equality follows from Bounded Convergence theorem and the continuity of $f_t$.

Comment: What makes the function $x\to \zeta(h,x)$ integrable?

Comment: Wouldn't $f_t(x,t+\zeta)$ be still continuous in (x,t)?

Comment: The usual mean value theorem says that for every $h$ and $x$ there is a $\zeta$. No information on the dependence on these quantities.  I would be happy to know whether something is known about this.

Comment: I usually avoid this in my courses by taking the difference $|\frac{1}{h}\int_a^b (f(x,t+h)-f(x,t)) - f_t(x,t))|$ and then estimate it with $|g|(b-a)\sup_{x}|f_t(x,t+\zeta)-f_t(x,t)|$. Uniform continuity of $f_t$ should yield the result.

Comment: I meant the $\frac{1}{h}$ behind the integral...